# Garch Model with Vix as external regressor un dummy rugarch r studio

Tags: programming, garch, vix

I would like to try to replicate this variance dummied model in r studio, to try to compare garch vs i.v in forecasting vol:
Data : S&P 500 log-return from 03.01.2020 to 31.12.2022
Ext regressor : Vix from 03.01.2020 to 31.12.2022.

[image]

[image]

Have you some idea of how to replicate this with the rugarch package?

I tought about computing the various garch with vixt-1 as external regressor and then regress the arch vol as dipendent variable.
If you have some insight let me know

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the original article that you mention ? They may have explained their methodology. You can easily add external regressors in a GARCH model in R. However, you want to add a dummy variable for the VIX. How would you do it ?

Regarding the implementation, the function ugarchspec() in rugarch package allows you to add external regressors (see args(ugarchspec) ) both in the mean and the variance model ! Hope this helps you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).